# Accidentally overwrote the default cluster-admin role

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

While trying to setup Helm for my cluster I declared the cluster-admin role which caused the overwriting of the default cluster-admin role. Now I don't have it in my cluster anymore. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new one with the following yaml:

**cluster-admin.yaml**:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: cluster-admin
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- nonResourceURLs:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

Create clusterRole:

```
$ kubectl apply -f cluster-admin.yaml
```

N.B.:

- `rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"` is given for [Auto-reconciliation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#auto-reconciliation).
- `kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults` is added by the API server. This label is used to represent [Default roles and role bindings](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#default-roles-and-role-bindings).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had to delete the tiller pod and service and recreate it again for it to attach to newly created cluster-admin role.